# Why does PHP throw source code indentation out?

Tags: php

For a while I have wondered why PHP throws source code indentation out.

### Example

**PHP:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  swfobject.embedSWF("a.swf", "a", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "a.swf", params); 
  params.1 = "<?php echo implode(',', $_POST['1']); ?>";
  params.2 = "<?php echo $_POST['2']; ?>";
  params.3 = "<?php echo $_POST['3']; ?>";
  <?php if ($_POST['4']) { ?>params.5 = "/mode <?php echo $_POST['2']; ?> +D";<?php } ?>
  params.6 = "Test";
</script>
```

**Generates source code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  swfobject.embedSWF("a.swf", "a", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "a.swf", params); 
  params.1 = "A";
  params.2 = "B";
  params.3 = "C";
  params.5 = "/mode B +D";
        params.6 = "Test";
</script>
```

Why does PHP throw source code indentation out on the next row, and how can I stop it from making my code ugly?

Comment: You have to insert indentation in the PHP if you want to maintain it. To do that you us `"\t"` for a tab.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't have any TAB in this file? Why does PHP alter the line below? There is no PHP code in the line ...

Comment: @smw Just don't worry about 'ugly' sourcecode ;)

Comment: No, I'm looking at `View Source` in browser. When I remove `params.5` line with PHP, `params.6` looks normal. Why does the `params.5` line throw out `params.6`?

Comment: @daanTracebuzz but I do :/

Comment: PHP's closing tag does funky stuff. It's obsolete as to why it does it but it's never been changed.

Comment: I notice it only happens when using `if`, all the other PHP echos don't break indentation on the next line ...

Comment: I would worry more about the use of Flash where loads of people use mobile devices to access my pages than I would about ugly source code ;-)

Comment: @ChipDean It's a question none-the-less, that nobody has yet answered, right?

Comment: @jeroen Mobile users filtered to `m.blah` way before this happens ;)

Comment: I was wondering the same either.But eventually, for optimizing reasons you should minimize your html code so it won't matter no more.

Comment: @SMW I hate it when that happens...

Comment: Maybe only open the PHP once? `<?php if ($_POST['4']) {  echo 'params.5 = "/mode ' . $_POST['2'] . ' +D';}?>` ... or do all the outputting in the PHP.

Comment: This is a stupid question, but are you sure you haven't mixed tabs and spaces in the original file? I don't think this has anything to do with PHP or its close tag as PHP is a tempting engine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is not nice. Anybody who doesn't care about the source code will not get a job with us. Ugly source codes are the source of all evil! No, just kidding.

However, you make a basic mistake in your code by mixing PHP and HTML in the way you do. Yes, I know it can be done, but should you? Is your PHP code very readable? I think not.

This is the way I would code it:

```
<?php
  // get parameters
  $params[1] = implode(',', $_POST['1']);
  $params[2] = $_POST['2'];
  $params[3] = $_POST['3'];
  if ($_POST['4']) $params[5] = "/mode {$_POST['2']} +D";
  $params[6] = "Test";

  // create javascript
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.PHP_EOL.
       '  swfobject.embedSWF("a.swf","a","100%","100%","10.0.0","a.swf",params);'.PHP_EOL;
  foreach ($params as $no => $value) {
    echo "  params.$no = \"$value\";".PHP_EOL;
  }
  echo '</script>';
?>
```

In other words: You have a powerful programming language, why not use it? Since all output is now done by PHP you have full control over it.

There are still many things wrong with this code, but that's for another time.